# Buffer Size needed

Tags: java, buffer

I am writing a java program in which I read 7200 bytes of data. My default block size on the Mac is 512 bytes. I am using PipedInputStream (int blockSize). In this case, what would be he optimal block size to use? I'm trying to make this as efficient as possible, so a single read would be optimal.

Comment: The default value will most likely be just fine. You can profile it then for actual results, instead of making wild guesses at premature optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimal block size for I/O operations can be determined by executing the following command from a terminal window prompt:

```
stat -f %k
```

Comment: When I do this it returns 131072. I need to translate this to an int since the argument calls for Buffer size as an int. Assuming that an int is 32 bits would this translate to PipedInputStream(4096) ?